# Как по правилам ООП правильно организовать хранение состояния объекта?

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть собственный объект - кнопка. Есть у него несколько стилей, состоящих из: Размера (int), надписи (string), цвета (System.Drawing.Color).
Допустим кнопка может иметь три состояния:

```
(1, "A", Color.Blue),
(2, "B", Color.Red),
(3, "C", Color.Green)
```

Как их лучше хранить? Да так, чтоб можно было переключаться по ним вызывая, методы Next() и Prev().

Сделал так:
Класс, хранящий эти поля:

```
    internal class StyleValueClass
    {
        public readonly int Id;
        public readonly string Name;
        public readonly Color ColorValue;

        public StyleValueClass(int id, string name, Color colorValue)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            ColorValue = colorValue;
        }

        public StyleValueClass Next(StyleValueСontainer container)
        {
            //return next
        }
    }
```

Также объект, хранящий эти объекты:

```
 internal class StyleValueСontainer 
    {
        StyleValueClass[] styleValue;

        public StyleValueСontainer(StyleValueClass[] StyleValue)
        {
            styleValue = StyleValue;
        }

        public StyleValueClass this[int index]
        {
            get { return StyleValue[index]; }
            set { StylerValue[index] = value; }
        }
    }
```

И у кнопки уже создаю поле в котором грубо забиваю все состояния:

```
        internal static readonly StyleValueСontainer StyleProp = new StyleValueСontainer(new[] 
        { 
            new StyleValueClass(1, "A", Color.Blue),
            new StyleValueClass(2, "B", Color.Red),
            new StyleValueClass(3, "C", Color.Green),
        });
```

Чую, что я делаю ерунду, т.к. если понадобится добавить новое свойство кнопки (например shape) или добавить еще одно состояние (например new StyleValueClass(4, "D", Color.Black), то получается очень тесное связывание.

Как лучше организовать?

Comment: в классе StyleValueСontainer у вас русская буква С, поправьте в коде

Comment: Методам Next и Prev следует быть в StyleValueContainer, а не в StyleValueClass.

Comment: Стоит предоставить реальную задачу, которую вы решаете, ибо сейчас очень обрезано все написано, из-за чего нельзя сказать точно, как правильней вам поступить, ибо например в WPF проекте и выше, если вы вот так в коде будете хранить стили, цвета, и прочее, то это очень плохо, ибо подобному место в XAML с его триггерами, стилями, привязками, и т.д.

Comment: Если абстрагироваться от этого всего, то у вас должна быть абстракция, интерфейсы, и др., где есть условный `interface IItem { общие методы и свойства }`, есть коллекция, к примеру `List<IItem> Items {get; set;}`, далее делаете производные, допустим  `interface IButtonItem : IItem { методы/свойства для кнопок }`, ну и реализуете `class ButtonItem : IButtonItem { реализация }`, аналогично для всех остальных объектов, там уж сами смотрите сколько слоев абстракции вам нужно, можно обойтись и одним интерфейсом. Ну и дальше заполняете `Items.Add(new ButtonItem())`, остается подогнать под это UI.

Answer (score -1):

ООП не занимается неким хранением состояний чего бы то ни было.
ООП - это абстрактная парадигма, прежде всего. И для ООП нет разницы какого цвета кнопка, или что написано на этой кнопке, и так далее.

В данном случае цвет/строка на кнопке - это реализация ООП, т.е. есть абстракция кнопки, а есть то что написано на кнопке и например цвет кнопки. Но всё это НЕ касается ооп-абстракций, но касается реализаций этих ооп-абстракций. Однако же реализация этих абстракций к ООП никакого отношения не имеет.

Иначе говоря:
Парадигма ООП не может различить красную и синюю кнопку. НИКАК. А значит для ООП эти кнопки одинаковые. В пределах абстракций ооп - одинаковые, разницы нет. И конечно же для различия этого существует например функциональщина, только это уже не ооп.

ООП предельно простая штука. Ищите общее - выделяйте это общее - получите ТИП. Но навыделяя много всякого разного общего - вы получите МНОГО ТИПОВ.

Абстракция это - набор абстрактных типов. Некий набор абстрактных типов объединяется под условной абстракцией. НО. "Мы" же уже выше описали то, что ООП не занимается реализацией, а значит должен быть "посредник" - между реализацией и абстракцией.

В вашем случае типы - это строки, цвета и так далее.
Объединяя эти типы - вы можете получить абстракцию, и в вашем случае абстракция это и есть объединение типов цветов/строк. В вашем случае абстракция объединяет НЕ реализованные цвет/строку, и это называется абстракцией кнопки.

Далее это всё нужно как то реализовать, реализуется это через интерфейсы. Т.е. ваша кнопка будет иметь интерфейсы IColorable, IStringable и так далее. Это посредник между абстракцией и реализацией. Абстракция "торчит наружу" вовсе не конкретными типами, а абстрактными типами. Проблем нет. Это ООП.

Итого:

```
public interface IColorable // что то "цветообразное"
{
    // Конкретные методы цвета (не реализация)
}
public interface IStringable // что то "строкообразное"
{
    // Конкретные методы надписей (не реализация)
}
public class Button : IColorable, IStringable
{
    // Приватные поля цвета/надписи

    // Конкретные методы цвета (реализация)
    // Конкретные методы надписей (реализация)
}
```

И понятное дело, что интерфейсы нужно объединить, в интерфейс чего то, что называется чем то "кнопкообразным":

```
public interface IButtonable // что то "кнопкообразное"
    : IColorable, IStringable
{
    // Конкретные методы кнопки (не реализация)
    // Но они же есть:
    // Конкретные методы цвета (не реализация)
    // Конкретные методы надписей (не реализация)
}
public class Button : IButtonable
{
    // Приватные поля цвета/надписи

    // Конкретные методы кнопки (реализация)
    // Конкретные методы цвета (реализация)
    // Конкретные методы надписей (реализация)
}
```

И тут встаёт другая проблема, впрочем, это не проблема ООП. А как хранить в полях не конкретный тип, а любой тип? Для этого существуют типы-обобщения. Впрочем это НЕ типы - это условность языка и компилятора. Т.е. если вы не знаете какой конкретный тип цвета/строки ("мы" можем иметь собственные реализации цвета/строки), то и нужно определить конкретный тип - не как тип, а как обобщённый тип, и это уловка языка/компилятора, это НЕ ооп.

Совсем итого:

```
public interface IButtonable // что то "кнопкообразное"
    : IColorable<TColor>, IStringable<TString>
{
    // Конкретные методы кнопки (не реализация)
    // Но они же есть:
    // Конкретные методы цвета (не реализация)
    // Конкретные методы надписей (не реализация)
}
public class Button<TColor, TString> : IButtonable
{
    // Приватные поля цвета/надписи
    // Работают не на конкретных типах, а на обобщённых типах

    // Конкретные методы кнопки (реализация)
    // Конкретные методы цвета (реализация)
    // Конкретные методы надписей (реализация)
}
```

И так далее. Тут можно уходить в абстракции всё дальше и глубже. Например можно создать обобщённый класс-хранилище обобщённых полей. Затем от него наследовать Button. Итд итп. И накручивать абстракции на абстракции можно бесконечно. А зачем? Существует некоторый "предел" понимания этого.

Что является чем по отношению к чему?

Если вы можете ответить на этот вопрос - ваши абстракции хороши. А если не можете? Значит что-то "не то". Оно может быть криво спроектированным, или же слишком глубоким, слишком абстрактным. И то и другое - плохо. Перепроектировать можно всегда и это не проблема. Но и "упарываться в абстрактность" тоже не стоит - возникает проблема понимания всего этого - это когда уже не понятно - а что является чем по отношению к чему НА САМОМ ДЕЛЕ?

П.С. Методам Next и Previous следует быть, например, в абстракции Buttons.